# Web API Returning Nested JSON Values

Tags: c#, sql, json, asp.net-web-api

I am working with a JSON structure being returned by a web api, but but have a problem.

Say, I have two tables, `Teams` and `Players`. They are joined by `TeamID` (PK on Teams and FK on Players).

I want my API call to return some JSON format similar as below:

```
[
    {
        TeamId: 1,
        TeamName: 'Chicago Bulls',
        TeamPlayers: [
            {PlayerId: 1, PlayerName: 'Pau Gasol'},
            {PlayerId: 2, PlayerName: 'Derrick Rose'},
            {PlayerId: 3, PlayerName: 'Joakim Noah'},
            {PlayerId: 4, PlayerName: 'Jimmy Butler'},
            {PlayerId: 5, PlayerName: 'Taj Gibson'}]
    },
    {
        TeamId: 2,
        TeamName: 'Cleveland Cavaliers',
        TeamPlayers: [
            {PlayerId: 1, PlayerName: 'Lebron James'},
            {PlayerId: 2, PlayerName: 'Kyrie Irving'},
            {PlayerId: 3, PlayerName: 'Anderson Varejao'},
            {PlayerId: 4, PlayerName: 'Dion Waiters'},
            {PlayerId: 5, PlayerName: 'Shawn Marion'}]
    },
    {
        TeamId: 3,
        TeamName: 'Los Angeles Clippers',
        TeamPlayers: [
            {PlayerId: 1, PlayerName: 'Chris Paul'},
            {PlayerId: 2, PlayerName: 'Blake Griffin'},
            {PlayerId: 3, PlayerName: 'DeAndre Jordan'},
            {PlayerId: 4, PlayerName: 'Jamal Crawford'},
            {PlayerId: 5, PlayerName: 'Matt Barnes'}]
    }
]
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using MyApp.Models;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class TeamsController : ApiController
    {
        private DataModel db = new DataModel();

        // GET: api/teams
        public IQueryable<TeamsWithPlayers> GetTeamsAndPlayers()
        {
            var query = from x in db.Teams
                        join y in db.Players on x.TeamId equals y.TeamId
                        select
                        {
                            // This is where I need some help...
                        }
        }
    }
}
```

TeamAndPlayer Class:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class TeamAndPlayers
    {
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public Players players { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Players Class:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class Players 
    {
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can someone provide some insight?

Comment: Your JSON structure doesn't match your models ! in the JSON you return an array of TeamPlayers, while your TeamAndPlayers has a single Player but named Players.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- I will assume that the JSON structure is the source of truth here not the models (TeamWithPlayers/Players) - see my comments.
- My solution assumes that you are using Entity Framework to retrieve the data from the database because I am using "Include" method, but can replace it to use "Join".

1- Define TeamDto and PlayerDto classes to be like :

```
public class TeamDto
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PlayerDto> TeamPlayers { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerDto
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
}
```

2- Your TeamsController will be like this:

```
public class TeamsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly TeamDbContext _dbContext = new TeamDbContext();

    // GET api/teams
    public IEnumerable<TeamDto> GetTeamsAndPlayers()
    {
        var teams = _dbContext
            .Teams
            .Include("Players") // Load the players associated with each Team, (this depends on your declaration, but you mentioned that there is a FK from Player => TeamId)
            // you can use the join if you like or if you don't use entity framework where you cannot call Include, but the following code will stay the same 
            .Select(t => new TeamDto
            {
                TeamId = t.TeamId,
                TeamName = t.TeamName,
                TeamPlayers = t.Players.Select(p => new PlayerDto
                    {
                        PlayerId = p.PlayerId, 
                        PlayerName = p.PlayerName
                    })
            }).ToList();

        return teams;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer to show how it would look if you didn't have a FK relationship. Thanks

Comment: My frieand said that you were really great. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var query = from x in db.Teams
    join y in db.Players on x.TeamId equals y.TeamId
    select new TeamsWithPlayers
    {
      TeamId = x.Id,
      TeamName= x.TeamName,
      Players = y
    }.ToList();
```

Comment: Your query will not return the required structure, pay attention to the model declaration and your query, you will notice that your query returns TeamId in the TeamsPlayer, and Players is not a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Love the suggested answer, VERY HELPFUL!

I used the suggested answer to make a similar solution for msyelf for learning and then tried to fit the above solution code into a getbyid method.

I had a couple of struggles but came up with the following working solution, in case anyone ever stumbles across this post like I did and wants to know how to use the above solution with a getbyid method.

Here is the default WebAPI getbyid method that VS created:

```
    // GET: api/teams/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(teams))]
    public IHttpActionResult Getteams(long id)
    {
        teams teams = db.teams.Find(id);
        if (teams == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

       return Ok(teams);
    }
```

Here is the updated Getbyid method using the structure used for the answer in this post:

```
    // GET: api/teams/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(teams))]
    public IHttpActionResult Getteams(long id)
    {
            var teams = _dbContext
            .Teams
            .Where(t => t.TeamId == id)
            .Include("Players")
            .Select(t => new TeamDto
            {
                TeamId = t.TeamId,
                TeamName = t.TeamName,
                TeamPlayers = t.Players.Select(p => new PlayerDto
                    {
                        PlayerId = p.PlayerId, 
                        PlayerName = p.PlayerName
                    })
            })
        });

        if (request == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(requests);
    }
```